# Posts are not shown, as I am using vue.js in laravel but it gives the 404 error

Tags: controller, routes, vue.js, laravel-5.5

**This is my *app.js* file where the response is shown on the console, but it gives the error. I don't know why**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('posts', require('./components/posts.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        blog:{},
    },
    mounted(){
        axios.post('/getPosts')
          .then(response => {
            this.blog = response.data.data
            //console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
});
```

**This is my route which show that page of *getPosts* which is not displaying**

```
Route::post('getPosts','PostController@getAllPosts');
```

**This is my *posts.vue* which holding the template for posts**

```
<template>
    <div class="post-preview">
        <a href="slug">
            <h2 class="post-title">
                {{ title }}
            </h2>
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                {{ subtitle }}
            </h3>
        </a>
        <p class="post-meta">Posted by
            <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                {{ created_at }}  
            <a href="">
                <small>0</small>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       props:[
        'title','subtitle','created_at'
       ]
    }
</script>
```

**In my *blog.blade.php* while I wrote this**

```
<posts 
     v-for='value in blog'
    :title='value.title'
    :subtitle='value.subtitle'
    :created_at='value.created_at'     
></posts>
```

I am not getting this page I don't know why! I got this error.
**POST http://localhost:8080/getPosts 404 (Not Found)**
I am also attaching image for the error

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a Laravel Routing issue more than a view issue, have you tried using something like postman to test the routing? as well can we see your routes/web.php file as your route looks correct but there may be something in the rest of the file preventing it from routing properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the issue. Your web-server configuration is not compatible with your request.

[image: A cropped image outlining the issue]

What it looks like is that your server is expecting `getPosts` to be in the `website/public` endpoint
Changing your Axios call to `axios.post('/website/public/getPosts')` or `axios.post('getPosts')` should solve the 404 issue.

You can also change your configuration so that `http://localhost:8080` points to your Laravel public directory; which may reflect a production environment better.